# RTCMultiConnection users streams keeps alive

Tags: javascript, webrtc

Im using webRTC plugin named (RTCMultiConnection) but if user has his cam on and leave somehow his session stays alive. Because if user1 opens cam, than leaves, again comes back and opens cam than it's not able to join it's cam.

Im trying to append the new connections like;

```
Webcam.connection.onNewSession = function(session) {
    console.log("On new session")
    createSession: function(session){
        Webcam.sessions[session.sessionid] = session;

        $("div").append($("<div />", {
            class: "webcam-live ct icon-isight",
            html: "LIVE"
        }));    
    }
};
```

First time opening the cam it appends whenever same user leaves and comesback it doesnt trigger for others. But if take another username than it sends its to new users

[Source](https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/RTCMultiConnection/video-broadcasting.html)

Comment: Please switch to [RTCMultiConnection-v3](https://github.com/muaz-khan/RTCMultiConnection/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md); and it may fix the issue.